# Installer for Windows application

Tags: windows, nsis

I have to create an installation file for ActiveX components. This ActiveX components will be downloaded as an *.exe installer file, executing this installer file will install the required ActiveX components on the user's PC.

To create such an installation file I came across two installer software -

- Install Shield
- NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)

So which of the above option is preferable or any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing InstallShield has going for it is its IDE.  And as it turns out, it works decently well for very basic installers when you don't need to write a line of code.  However, when you need to create custom tasks and get into InstallShield's scripting language, it's a very clunky and unpleasant experience.

In terms of reliability, flexibility, speed, and size, NSIS is far superior to InstallShield.  I know it's a bold claim.  But you can read about my install system saga here and what led me to NSIS...  http://swortham.blogspot.com/2008/02/nsis-another-gem-from-nullsoft.html

Comment: It's not such a bold claim when you consider that NASA, Google, Mozilla, Sun Microsystems, Adobe, and many more rely on it for installation of many of their consumer-level products.

source: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Users

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, you can also create an installer project for your Active X which uses the windows installer.

Answer (score -1):

InstallShield is superior to NSIS. However, because NSIS is free and enough for your needs, I recommend using it.

Comment: I read more about Install shield and NSIS. Install Shield appears to be powerful, but I will use NSIS since its free.
Thanks :)